# RabbitMQ not accesible via cli

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

After installing RabbitMQ I can login via the browser https://localhost:15671/openlab/rabbitmq/#/

However when I try to use the cli tool, it throws me the following error:

```
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.10.7\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat status
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@xxx-161'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@xxx-161
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@xxx-161']

rabbit@xxx-161:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on xxx-161
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: check if the Erlang cookie is identical for all server nodes and CLI tools
  * suggestion: check if all server nodes and CLI tools use consistent hostnames when addressing each other
  * suggestion: check if inter-node connections may be configured to use TLS. If so, all nodes and CLI tools must do that
   * suggestion: see the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-459-rabbit@xxx-161'
 * effective user's home directory: c:/Users/Administrator
 * Erlang cookie hash: FNgYpbJciVHLToFZiB1dnw==
```

I do not have the slighest clue what the error could be. Rabbit logs do not log any errors as well.

My `.erlang.cookie` files are identical

Any help?